# PostgreSQL missing from clause entry for table in function

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, postgresql-9.6

I have the following function that handles a trigger on insert or update:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ticketChangeFunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dw.FactSalesHeader (DateKey, LocationKey, EmployeeKey, AppointmentTypeKey, TicketStatusTypeKey, TicketID,TotalAmount, IsNewPatient, IsActive)
        SELECT d.date_key, COALESCE(l.LocationKey, 0), COALESCE(e.EmployeeKey, 0), COALESCE(a.AppointmentTypeKey, 0), COALESCE(ts.TicketStatusTypeKey, 0), NEW.ticket_id,
        NEW.total_amount, NEW.is_new_patient, NEW.is_active
        FROM db1.tickets t
        JOIN dw.DimDate d on t.ticket_date = d.db_date
        LEFT JOIN dw.DimLocation l on NEW.location_id = l.LocationID
        LEFT JOIN dw.DimEmployee e on NEW.counselor_id = e.EmployeeID
        LEFT JOIN dw.DimAppointmentType a on NEW.office_visit_ind = a.AppointmentTypeFlagAttribute
        LEFT JOIN dw.DimTicketStatus ts on NEW.ticket2_status = ts.TicketStatusTypeID
        ON CONFLICT (TicketID)
        DO UPDATE
        SET DateKey = d.date_key, 
        LocationKey = COALESCE(l.LocationKey, 0), 
        EmployeeKey = COALESCE(e.EmployeeKey, 0), 
        AppointmentTypeKey = COALESCE(a.AppointmentTypeKey, 0), 
        TicketStatusTypeKey = COALESCE(ts.TicketStatusTypeKey, 0), 
        TotalAmount = NEW.total_amount, 
        IsNewPatient = NEW.is_new_patient, 
        IsActive = NEW.is_active;
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get the error: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "d"`

I thought maybe it was somehow related to the `db1.tickets` table that I'm not technically using in the query. I've tried taking out that bit and just doing `FROM dw.DimDate` with `WHERE d.date_key = NEW.ticket_date`, and that gives the same error.

There are a lot of these types of questions on SO, but I haven't found one that addresses this particular scenario, as I feel like it has something to do with it being inside of this trigger function.

The function gets called from this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tickets AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON db1.tickets
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ticketChangeFunc();
```

I'm also wondering if using the `ON CONFLICT UPDATE` clause updates every row when it finds a match regardless of whether the values differ? Is there a performance impact to this, and if so, is there a way to check for equality of each field and do nothing if there are no differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may happen to run into this in the future, the solution for me was to add a conditional to the function and handle inserts separately from updates:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ticketChangeFunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
            INSERT INTO dw.FactSalesHeader (DateKey, LocationKey, EmployeeKey, AppointmentTypeKey, TicketStatusTypeKey, TicketID, TotalAmount, IsNewPatient, IsActive)
            SELECT d.date_key, COALESCE(l.LocationKey, 0), COALESCE(e.EmployeeKey, 0), COALESCE(a.AppointmentTypeKey, 0), COALESCE(ts.TicketStatusTypeKey, 0), NEW.ticket_id, 
            NEW.total_amount, NEW.is_new_patient, NEW.is_active
            FROM db1.tickets t
            JOIN dw.DimDate d ON NEW.ticket_date = d.db_date
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimLocation l ON NEW.location_id = l.LocationID
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimEmployee e ON NEW.counselor_id = e.EmployeeID
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimAppointmentType a ON NEW.office_visit_ind = a.AppointmentTypeFlagAttribute
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimTicketStatus ts ON NEW.ticket2_status = ts.TicketStatusTypeID;        
        ELSE
            UPDATE dw.FactSalesHeader 
            SET DateKey = CAST(TO_CHAR(NEW.ticket_date, 'YYYYMMDD') as integer),
            LocationKey = COALESCE(l.LocationKey, 0), 
            EmployeeKey = COALESCE(e.EmployeeKey, 0),
            AppointmentTypeKey = COALESCE(a.AppointmentTypeKey, 0),
            TicketStatusTypeKey = COALESCE(ts.TicketStatusTypeKey, 0),
            TotalAmount = NEW.total_amount, 
            IsNewPatient = NEW.is_new_patient, 
            IsActive = NEW.is_active
            FROM dw.FactSalesHeader hdr
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimLocation l ON NEW.location_id = l.LocationID
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimEmployee e ON NEW.counselor_id = e.EmployeeID
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimAppointmentType a ON NEW.office_visit_ind = a.AppointmentTypeFlagAttribute
            LEFT JOIN dw.DimTicketStatus ts ON NEW.ticket2_status = ts.TicketStatusTypeID
            WHERE hdr.TicketID = NEW.ticket_id;
        END IF;        
    RETURN NULL;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```